# Fill Blanks type format in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to Android. How to create fill the blanks format in the Android Studio.

For ex: If my answer is Android, then I need to give blanks like below.

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _
```

And user need to type the answer in those blanks.

I have tried this:

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context=".MainActivity" >



<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="enter_text" android:inputType="text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do 2 things:
1) Determine the length of answer String. In this case it will be 7
2) Than run a for loop and create edittext dynamically.

```
for(int i=0; i<{your ans length}; i++)
{
       EditText ed = new EditText();
       //set tag to it get value according to it
}
```